# Microsoft Access and Java JDBC-ODBC Error

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

Trying to insert some values in a Microsoft access  database using java.

I can an error however,

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified
>   DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and
>   Application Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

To create the data source im using SysWoW64 > odbcad32 and adding it the datasource to system DNS. I say this as i have seen else where there are problems which occur with 64bit systems. However it  still doesn't work for me.

Microsoft Office 32bit.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class AuctionHouseJDBC {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String theItem = "Car";
        String theClient="Name";
        String theMessage="1001";



Connection conn =null; // Create connection object

        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver Found");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Driver Not Found");
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        // connecting to database
        try{
            String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=AuctionHouseDatabase.accdb;";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database,"","");

            System.out.println("Conn Found");
        }
        catch(SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("Conn Not Found");
            System.err.println(se);
        }
        // Create select statement and execute it

        try{        
            /*String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO AuctionHouse VALUES (  "
                    +"'" +theItem+"', "  
                    +"'" +theClient+"', "
                    +"'" +theMessage+"')";  
            */

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String insertSQL = "Insert into AuctionHouse VALUES ('Item','Name','Price')";

             stmt.executeUpdate(insertSQL);
            // Retrieve the results

            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SqlStatment Not Found");
            System.err.println(se);
        }

    }

}
```

StaceTrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

Microsoft Office 64bit

Ive installed 64 bit version and now im gettin an error [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Not a valid file name.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35018/Access-MS-Access-Databases-from-Java That's simply not how you access a MS Access DB and it's trying to tell you that.

Comment: I'm still getting a data source not found error.

Answer (score 3):

At first make sure you can access that database via ODBC. Make DSN in `odbcad32` for both 64 and 32 bit systems. Then as JDBC connect string use: `jdbc:odbc:[CreatedDSN]`. If you cannot connect to Access in 64 bit version of `odbcad32` then make sure it works in 32 bit version of `odbcad32` and make sure you use 32 bit version of Java.

Also have a look at other responses to: [Can't connect to MS Access DB with Windows-64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782957/cant-connect-to-ms-access-db-with-windows-64bit)

Especially interesting is link to: http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/