# Password not recognized in Java for MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access-2010, password-protection, jdbc-odbc

I have to import data from a MySQL DB to a MS Access DB. I use JDK8 on a Windows7Pro 64 bit.

When I run the code I get an exception at the following line of code:

```
String database = .../
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "mypw");
```

and the error is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Not a valid password
```

However, when I open the db via MSAccess the password is accepted. What am I missing? Maybe something related to the user value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776320/microsoft-access-and-java-jdbc-odbc-error

Comment: @prash. I dunno! Mine yt's the same code and procedure I always use! What it changes now, is that the db is protected by password!

Comment: can u try the username as "Admin"

Comment: !!! Yes, it works! But is works also with another random username! I don't understand why! MS's stuffs!

Comment: haha.. post that as a different question. I think that's good one, but I don't know!

Comment: I'm astonished! Really!

Comment: Probably You should run java as Administrator (permission problem)
rgds,-az

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the username as "Admin"

I don't know why exactly it work, but I know it works.